# Is there any way to improve AR vertical plane detection?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality

I have a problem with detecting vertical planes in an `ARSession` using a `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration` with `planeDetection` set to `.vertical` when plane is white or, it is in an environment with bad lightning. Is there any way to improve detecting vertical planes? Or I can't do anything about this?
This is my code for detecting objects

```
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    configuration.planeDetection = .vertical
    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
```

Comment: This is quite likely that either only Apple can fix or would be way to complicated to explain here. Unless your planning to write your own plane detection code/library you will need to wait for an update to the AR framework itself

Answer (score -1):

the plane detection is based on ARKit's ability to find feature points in each frame, so bad lighting and blank untextured surfaces is pretty much impossible because there will be no feature points. you could however prompt the user to place their own planes on the vertical surface by indicating the corners using a ARMeasure sort of interface